# Fetching data based on days is returning an empty array in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, time, mongodb-query

I want to fetch data from mongoDB database based on days(Sunday, Monday etc.) using `day.js` library but it is returning an empty array

Sample data from the database `parkings` collection:

```
{
  "merchantId": {
    "$oid": "62c950dfc96c2b690028be88"
  },
  "contactInfo": {
    "name": "Claudia Shields",
    "phoneNumber": 8904672101
  },
  "location": {
    "address": "737 applegate court",
    "city": "bowie",
    "state": "rhode island",
    "country": "greece",
    "zipCode": 10825
  },
  "price": 16,
  "parkingType": "residence",
  "parkingInfo": [
    {
      "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d12053cb03235286511d55"
      },
      "default": []
    }
  ],
  "totalSpots": [
    127
  ],
  "coordinates": {
    "lng": 34.048954,
    "lat": 10.299556
  },
  "status": "active",
  "isFeePaid": false,
  "parkingZone": [],
  "availability": [
    {
      "day": "Saturday",
      "startTime": "09:00",
      "endTime": "14:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13355bd1ad85d85ae4b4b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Monday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13375bd1ad85d85ae4b4f"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d1337cbd1ad85d85ae4b53"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Wednesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13383bd1ad85d85ae4b57"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Thursday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13390bd1ad85d85ae4b5b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Friday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13396bd1ad85d85ae4b5f"
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

The thing to note here is that, In the database it is stored as a **day**

I am sending the following request from the postman:

```
{
    "city":"edmund",
    "startTime": "2022-07-20 11:00",
    "duration":{
        "days":"0",
        "hours":"5",
        "minutes":10
    }
}
```

Here, I am sending the **date**

Route to fetch the parking availability from the database:

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    endTime = getEndTime(req.body.startTime, req.body.duration);
    const startTime = dayjs(req.body.startTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").format("dddd");

    let parkings = await Parking.find({
      "location.city": req.body.city,
      "availability.day": startTime,
    });
    console.log(parkings);

    parkingList = [];
    parkings.filter((parking) => {
      if (isParkingAvailable(parking.availability, req.body.startTime, endTime))
        isParkingAvailable(parking.availability);
      parkingList.push(parking);
    });

    res.status(200).send(parkingList);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

If I log the *startTime* then it is displaying Wednesday in the console but it is not fetching data based on that instead it is returning an empty array if log the `parkings`

Comment: First try Parking.find({}). If this works, try hardcoded value Parking.find({'availability.day': 'Wednesday'}). If this works, try Parking.find({ "location.city": 'bowie', 'availability.day': 'Wednesday' }); (suppose, this one won't work)...

Comment: It is behaving weirdly now, ```Parking.find({})``` returns all the data. ```Parking.find({"location.city": "bowie","availability.day": "Wednesday"});``` is also returning matched data only(2 collections) but ```Parking.find({"availability.day":"Wednesday"})``` is returning with city named bowie only. I have other collections as well in parkings with availability.day of wednesday But it returns only city named bowie @DraganS

Comment: @DraganS I have never mentioned bowie in my code anywhere

Comment: Line 11 - "city": "bowie",

Comment: Ok, no worries it is working completely fine I have made some changes in the schema and completely forgot it. But still I Want Show data only of day ```Wednesday``` only instead of showing all data of availability from Monday through Saturday. @DraganS

Comment: No, @DraganS Please don't leave me stranded here. I want to show data only of requested day. (eg. I am querying for wednesday then I want to show only data of wednesday) But I am getting all the data from monday to saturday like the first code-block. How to filter out that data??

Comment: Pls update DB content - my understanding is that you need only `Parking.find({
      "availability.day": startTime,
    });`
Also, check whether dayjs' format method returns name_of_day in the same format as defined by availability.day field

Comment: But I want to filter by city also and yes day.js format returns correct name of the day